# Scikit learn - ignore metadata features when training

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metadata, scikits

I want to map failed examples back to identifying metadata like `name, id,` etc so I can look more closely at them. The easiest way I can think to do this would be to leave the `id` field in the feature set when I call the fit function. However, I don't want the model to train on these metadata fields. Is there anyway to fit a model while ignoring some features? Or is there some better way to map failed examples back to their identifying metadata?

Comment: It's expected that you provide a [mre] showing the code that isn't quite doing what you want. (See [ask].)

Comment: I don't think there's much need to provide an example in this case. Essentially, a theoretical question about scikit's api and machine learning strategy in general. Perhaps this is the wrong board to post on though

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be looking at the "failed examples" in your test, not in your training dataset. I'm going to assume that is what you want to do - but it works the same way for training data also. The question becomes, how to set up the data set so that you can trace back individual data points that the model doesn't perform well on.

I'm also going to assume that your data is in a dataframe. Let's say you have the columns `[feature1, feature2, id]`. Then whatever shuffling and splitting into train/test/validation data you do, you do on the full data frame - features and metadata get moved together.

Finally, you pass `df[[feature1, feature2]]` to your model. Now your feature data and your full data are indexed in the exactly same way. After identifying the data point that it does not work well on, you can get its id and other metadata by looking at the original dataframe at the same index.

Comment: That's not strictly true. If you can't overfit your training data, you've got a problem with your model implementation. It's an incredibly useful and common test. But where did they say they were only looking at the training set, anyway?

Comment: I implied that they were from the `fit` method they want to use.